# How to use LZMA compress algorithm with next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, compression, lzma

Who knows how to compress video photo text, etc. through the lzma algorithm using the Next.js framework, I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Nowhere is there either a proper demonstration or an answer.
I'd be happy and grateful if you could help.

Answer (score 1):

Use fsfor filesystem and LZMA

```
const compressImage = (imagePath) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(imagePath, (readError, imageData) => {
      if (readError) {
        reject(readError);
        return;
      }

      lzma.compress(imageData, 9, (compressedData, compressError) => {
        if (compressError) {
          reject(compressError);
        } else {
          resolve(compressedData);
        }
      });
    });
  });
};
```

To use this

```
compressImage(imagePath)
  .then((compressedData) => {
    console.log('Image compressed successfully:', compressedData);
  })
```